# Why does python show "TclError : can't invoke "place" command: application has been destroyed" in the following code

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

def close_window():
    print ("")
    window.destroy()

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("750x350")

username = tk.Label(window, text = "Enter Username")

password = tk.Label(window, text = "Enter Password")

input1 = tk.Entry(window)

input2 = tk.Entry(window, show = "*")

confirm = tk.Button(text="Confirm", command = close_window()) 

input1.place(x=400, y=35)

input2.place(x=400, y=65)

username.place(x=150, y=35)

password.place(x=150, y=65)

confirm.place(x=400, y=100)

confirm.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I am trying to make a forum which closes itself once you click confirm. Also, i use spyder (just in case) and i have just started the concept of tkinter. I tried to find the answer on google but it was not so successful.

Comment: Please post the _full_ error message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're calling "close_window()" in this line: "confirm = tk.Button(text="Confirm", command = close_window()) "

Comment: you should pass the function close_window() like this  "confirm = tk.Button(text="Confirm", command = close_window )"

Comment: You might be trying to destroy the window twice. what you can do is try to destroy it and pass if it's already destroyed

Comment: try:
    window.destroy()
except:
    pass